# Is it possible to connect an Access form to a SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm migrating an Access DB to SQL Server and everything is slowly coming along but Im not sure how to connect the Access forms to the SQL Server views.

So far I have all the tables linked to SQL Server and Im working on migrating the Access queries into views, but Ive got this error, `A2SS0069: External variable cannot be converted`

which references a form in my Access file:

```
  SELECT TOP 9223372036854775807 WITH TIES 
      [AcuteHospitals].[NHSN_ID], 
      [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], 
      [Location_LOV].[Description] AS Location, 
      Sum([RateTable_CLABData].[clabcount]) AS [Number of CLABSI], 
      Sum([RateTable_CLABData].[numcldays]) AS [Central Line Days], 
      [RateTable_CLABData].[CLAB_Mean] AS [National Average]
   FROM 
      (([AcuteHospitals] 
         LEFT JOIN [RateTable_CLABData] 
         ON [AcuteHospitals].[NHSN_ID] = [RateTable_CLABData].[orgID]) 
         LEFT JOIN [Location_LOV] 
         ON [RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc] = [Location_LOV].[CDCLoc]) 
         LEFT JOIN [SummaryYQ_LOV] 
         ON [RateTable_CLABData].[summaryYQ] = [SummaryYQ_LOV].[StartDate]
   WHERE ((([SummaryYQ_LOV].[SummaryYQ]) = forms!YQ_Location.text5 ))
   GROUP BY 
      [AcuteHospitals].[NHSN_ID], 
      [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], 
      [Location_LOV].[Description], 
      [RateTable_CLABData].[CLAB_Mean], 
      [RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc]
   HAVING ((([RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc]) NOT LIKE '%ped%'))
   ORDER BY [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], [RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc]
```

Its the line `WHERE ((([SummaryYQ_LOV].[SummaryYQ]) = forms!YQ_Location.text5 ))`

So I need to know if it's possible and how to get this new view to connect with the Access form.

Comment: 9223372036854775807 is a big number......

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here

> WHERE ((([SummaryYQ_LOV].[SummaryYQ]) = **forms!YQ_Location.text5** ))

You cannot convert such Access query into a SQL View, but you can use [Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) instead and pass value from the field `forms!YQ_Location.text5` as parameter.

Also, you don't need this `TOP 9223372036854775807 WITH TIES` it is redundant.

Comment: yeah the number is just what SSMA spit out when I tried converting it. You wouldnt know how to build the Stored Procedure would you? Im seeing this stuff for the first time...

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference the Access form in a SQL View directly. You will need to rethink the logic in this. You could either create a number of Views with the appropriate values hard-coded (inadvisable) or convert the View to a [Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and pass the value in as a [parameter](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-parameters-inserts-and-updates).

For example (assuming the parameter is a string):

```
    create proc s_MyStoredProc

    @Location varchar(50)

    AS
    BEGIN
     SELECT 
      [AcuteHospitals].[NHSN_ID], 
      [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], 
      [Location_LOV].[Description] AS Location, 
      Sum([RateTable_CLABData].[clabcount]) AS [Number of CLABSI], 
      Sum([RateTable_CLABData].[numcldays]) AS [Central Line Days], 
      [RateTable_CLABData].[CLAB_Mean] AS [National Average]
   FROM 
      (([AcuteHospitals] 
         LEFT JOIN [RateTable_CLABData] 
         ON [AcuteHospitals].[NHSN_ID] = [RateTable_CLABData].[orgID]) 
         LEFT JOIN [Location_LOV] 
         ON [RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc] = [Location_LOV].[CDCLoc]) 
         LEFT JOIN [SummaryYQ_LOV] 
         ON [RateTable_CLABData].[summaryYQ] = [SummaryYQ_LOV].[StartDate]
   WHERE ((([SummaryYQ_LOV].[SummaryYQ]) = @Location ))
   GROUP BY 
      [AcuteHospitals].[NHSN_ID], 
      [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], 
      [Location_LOV].[Description], 
      [RateTable_CLABData].[CLAB_Mean], 
      [RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc]
   HAVING ((([RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc]) NOT LIKE '%ped%'))
   ORDER BY [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], [RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc]

END
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create the SQL server view, and then from the Access font end link to that view. It is easy, not much work.

As for any parameters? Just remove them from the query and views. You then just open up the report using a where clause from the Access client.

In fact using a Access form or report that is bound to a linked table (or in this case view)  is easy, and Access will ONLY pull down the reocrds you specifiy in the "where" clause of the open form or open report command.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has an excellent (and free) MS-Access to MS-SQL migration tool. It does a very good job of converting MS-Access queries. I haven't tried converting queries with form parameters, but it is certainly worth a look and you may learn some things as well, especially if you plan to convert other queries.  http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#oracle.